# Print lines not containing a Tab

Tags: shell, text-processing

I have a text file (around 15000 lines) that is supposed to contain two fields separated by a Tab in each line.

Is there a way to display the lines that do not contain a Tab separating the two fields?

Comment: `awk '!/\t/' file`...

Answer (score 0):

please try this i hope this is helpful for you

```
grep  -Pv '\t' "test.txt"
```

"v" option is use to invert matching and "P" for pattern

in below image last two line not contain tab

[image]

Comment: please approve my ans :) @Snowbell

Comment: is there a tool on this forum to approve your answer? I don't know. I have just started using this forum

Comment: see this image http://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.pngwe also get reputation